# In python, test for 1 or 3 consecutive instances of a string, but not 2 (without regex)

Tags: python, logic, control-flow

I am dealing with data in which...

`*` marks property A
`**` marks property B
`***` marks properties A & B

```
text1 = "spam*eggs"   # A
text2 = "eggs**spam"  # B
text3 = "spam***spam" # A & B
```

Testing for property B is easy,

```
"**" in <string>
```

but testing for property A with the same strategy would give a false positive with text2.

```
>>> "*" in text2
True
```

I want to test for property A. Is there a pythonic way to do this without using regular expressions? I don't want to use regex because I share code with beginner programmers who are not familiar with it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why you do not want to use regular expressions? Since they're perfect for this task.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not clear if you want to just test for Property A, as in the text, or A or C, as in the title. (C being A and B)

To just get `True` or `False` for 1 or 3 and not 2, you can use a code rephrasing of your logic:

```
result = '***' in x or (not  '**' in x and '*' in x)
```

To get the letter of `ABC` out depending on the pattern:

```
result = ['None','A','B','C'][('*' in x) + ('**' in x) + ('***' in x)]
```

To just test for Property A (one star) without failing on two or three. (EDIT: simplified this. If `**` is not there then neither is `***`):

```
isItA = '*' in x and not  '**' in x
```

Comment: Although these solutions require multiple traverses (unlike one other suggestion), all three are pythonic in my opinion. Very straighforward code. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I like `itertools` as much as the next person (well, maybe not Jon ;^) but they seem overkill for simple logic like this. Btw the first solution will only make one test if `***` is true -- it moves on as soon as the `or` condition is met.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
idx = txt.index('*')
if txt[idx+1] != '*':
    print 'A'
elif txt[idx+2] != '*':
    print 'B'
else:
    print 'A & B'
```

The above will raise exceptions for the corner cases - for example, if the string is not present, or if the string is the last character. This solution has the added benefit of performing a *single* traversal of the text (the call to `index()`).

Answer (score 2):

Without Regex, you could do something like this:

```
if "***" in mystr:
    print "Property A & B"
elif "**" in mystr:
    print "Property B"
elif "*" in mystr:
    print "Property A"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the occurrences of '*':

```
>>> text1.count('*')
1
>>> text2.count('*')
2
>>> text3.count('*')
3
```

So your check would be `text.count('*') in (1, 3)`

That said, I agree with the commenter - regular expressions are right for this kind of problem.

```
>>> properties = {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'A & B'}
>>> import re
>>> text = 'eggs***spam'
>>> match = re.search(r'\*+', text)
>>> if match:
...    print properties[len(match.group(0))]
... else:
...    print 'None'
A & B
```

Comment: `count` isn't going to work in all cases.  Take for example this string: "A*B*C*".  It _should_ belong to property A, but your solution will see 3 *'s and say property A & B.

Comment: Well, there's no reason to think that from the sample data the poster provides. But you're right, if that assumption doesn't hold.

Comment: All of the *'s in my data would be consecutive, so this solution works for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wouldn't say it's Pythonic, but you could group them and make sure the consecutive occurrences are of a certain length - either 1 or 3 to exclude `**` for instance, eg:

```
from itertools import groupby
print any(k=='*' and len(list(g)) in (1, 3) for k, g in groupby(s))
```